# How to get scenario name from a scenario outline in cucumber using java

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

Suppose I have a test case like -

```
*Scenario: Facebook login test
GIVEN I am a Facebook user
WHEN I enter my user name & password
THEN login should be successful*
```

How could I get the scenario name from the step definition methods corresponding to "I am a Facebook user" or "I enter my user name & password" or "login should be successful" ?

Step definitions methods are -

```
@Given("^I am a Facebook user$")
public void method1() {
 //some coding
 //I want to get the scenario name here
}

@When("^I enter my user name & password$")
public void method2() {
 //some coding
 //I want to get the scenario name here
}

@Then("^login should be successful$")
public void method3() {
 //some coding
 //I want to get the scenario name here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No @Bappa, it's possible, though your stepdefinition class is singleton and your tests are in parallel, see it be attacked with below approach by enhancing it with thread-safe static hash map variable used for storage:

```
public class StepDefinitions{
 private static HashMap<Integer,String> scenarios;

public StepDefinitions(){ //or even inside of your singleton's getInstance();
 if(scenarios == null)
   scenarios = new HashMap<Integer,String();
}

@Before
public void beforeHook(Scenario scenario) {
    addScenario(scenario.getName());
}

@When("your step definition")
public void stepDefinition1(){
   String scenario = getScenario(); //problem-o-solved here...
}


private void addScenario(String scenario){
     Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
     int threadID = currentThread.hashCode();
     scenarios.put(threadID,scenario);
}

private synchronized String getScenario(){
     Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
     int threadID = currentThread.hashCode();
     return scenarios.get(threadID);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `@Before` hook to get the current executing `Scenario` object.

```
@Before
public void beforeHook(Scenario scenario) {
     this.sce = scenario
     System......(scenario.getName())
     System......(scenario.getId())
}
```

You can access the stored scenario object in your step definitions.

Comment: The step definition class is a singletone class and 5-6 separate feature files are using that parallelly. Storing the scenario name in a variable will not work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the step definition, you can use `CucumberHelper.scenario.getName()`.

Based on this API you can use `getID`, `getSourceTagNames`, `getStatus` and `getClass` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to this very late, but Bhuvanesh Mani's answer can be simplified by using a ThreadLocal field. The following code does away with all the Thread manipulation and the helper methods while still remaining thread safe

```
public class StepDefinitions {
    private static ThreadLocal<String> localName;

    @Before
    public void beforeHook(Scenario scenario) {
        localName.set(scenario.getName());
    }

    @When("your step definition")
    public void stepDefinition1(){
        String scenario = localName.get();
    }
}
```